# JavaFX loading image from within project not recognized

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, load

I've tried for hours now to find a way of getting my image to load.
I have a project with a src folder and a res folder
My code is within my src folder and I try to access all of my resources through my res folder.

However, trying to load an image proves to be an amazingly difficult feat as nothing from the various sources that have offered help have worked.

```
Image undefinedIcon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/ids/no.png"));
```

This is the closest I would say I have gotten to having my resource load, but still to no avail.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recipe to get this working in a typical project setup:

1. Make sure both your "src" folder and your "res" folder are source folders and not just some folder within your project. (This is the Eclipse terminology. I don't know how this is called in other IDEs.)
2. Change the argument of getResourceAsStream to "/ids/no.png".

Now loading your image should work. It has the same effect as if you would copy your "ids" folder into the source folder.

Comment: my res folder is another folder at the same level as my src folder. I tried your approach but it didn't work

Comment: Yes, but it must be a source folder and not just some other folder. Which IDE are you using? In Eclipse you could right-click on this folder and select Build Path -> Use as Source Folder but I don't know how that is handled in other IDEs.